# Change flexslider animation style after initiated

Tags: jquery, flexslider

I was trying to change animation style from "Fade" to "Slide" after its initiated but all failed. Debug shows property value changed but visual animation doesn't change. I've tried with following code taken from  https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/issues/334

```
slider.setOpts = function(opts) {
  for (var opt in opts) {
    slider.vars[opt] = opts[opt];
  }
  slider.setup();
}

slider.getOpts = function() {
  return slider.vars;
}
```

and then

```
$(myslider).data('flexslider').setOpts({animation: 'swing', easing: 'swing', fade: false });
```

Could anybody help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `after` event and stop/restart the slider:

```
    $('.sliderDiv').flexslider({
        after: function (slider) {          
            slider.stop();
            slider.vars.animation = 'swing';
            slider.vars.fade = false;
            slider.play();
        }
    });
```

I used the start event to change the animation speed after the first load. Maybe it works for changing the animation type as well, but I did not try that.

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work for me. Btw, I'm creating slider from ajax content, so i want first slide to be show as fadeIn and others as slide but deliberately failing :(

Comment: I played around with this some more http://jsfiddle.net/f46scur2/1/ and indeed, the animation type is controlled by the internal "fade" property that does not get updated when you call setup("init"), so effectively it cannot be changed unless you patch the code. I suppose you could use an image overlay with CSS transition, or two separate sliders where you turn off the one with fading and turn on the one with sliding based on a slider or timer event.